# How to troubleshoot VPN issues between Azure VPN and VMWare SNX?

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

1. I have created Virtual Network Connection (policy based) in Azure.
2. I have created Connection for Site to Site(IPSec) which connects to VMWare-snx.
3. Connection status is "Connecting". (Also connecting status ok from VMWare SNX side)
4. I have VM in subnet. Both subnet is part of one VNet.

Test: I try to ping or RDP to VM in VMWare side VM, but do not have connection.

Q: Did I understand correctly that I should have automatically connection from all subnet in VNet. No routing is needed between Gateway Subnet and others?

Q: Is there any way to troubleshoot if ping passed Azure VPN? Azure Monitor tells something?

Instructions followed:
https://vzerotohero.com/2017/03/step-by-step-deploy-vmware-nsx-with-microsoft-azure-ipsec-vpn-site-to-site/

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to test your VPN [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-diagnose-on-premises-connectivity), specially [troubleshooting using Azure Network Watcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-diagnose-on-premises-connectivity#troubleshooting-using-azure-network-watcher). When establishing a VPN S2S all of routes are created automatically in your VNET where lives your Virtual Network Gateway according to your [Local Network Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal#LocalNetworkGateway) and your device VMWare-snx. In order to make sure that you have routes between Azure and you On-Premises, you can see [Effective Route](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem#diagnose-using-azure-portal) for your VM's NIC. Finally status must be connected and not connecting for your VPN connection, you can see details about [VPN devices and IPsec/IKE parameters for Site-to-Site VPN Gateway connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices).